# An ES JVM Unexpected Termination Error

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jvm

I am using Elasticsearch 1.6.2 that starts two instances in separate machines as a cluster. One day an instance shuts down unexpected while the other runs normally. 
The dead one left the hs_err.log file that is in the attachment. Can any one help me figure out what causes the collapsion?

One more thing that might help. The dead node rebuilt indices 5 mins before shutting down, and the rebuilt indices had been synchronised to the other node (the live one).

Many thanks!

[SO seems unable to upload file to please download the error log from here](https://github.com/LiangShang/MiscFiles/blob/master/hs_err_pid.log)

The error is

**Internal Error (sharedRuntime.cpp:814)**

`guarantee(cb->is_adapter_blob() || cb->is_method_handles_adapter_blob()) failed: exception happened outside interpreter, nmethods and vtable stubs (1)`

The Heap seems healthy:

`Heap
 par new generation   total 78656K, used 6286K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000c0350000, 0x00000000cfac0000)
  eden space 69952K,   3% used [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bb076288, 0x00000000bf250000)
  from space 8704K,  43% used [0x00000000bfad0000, 0x00000000bfe7d6c0, 0x00000000c0350000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x00000000bf250000, 0x00000000bf250000, 0x00000000bfad0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 486164K, used 357704K [0x00000000cfac0000, 0x00000000ed585000, 0x00000000fae00000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 75328K, used 45195K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000ff790000, 0x0000000100000000)`

Comment: There is no attachment

Comment: Upload attachment to another place:)

Answer (score 0):

From crash logs it is clear that you are using linux kernel 2.6.32 (uname:Linux 2.6.32504.el6.x86_64). This issue is more of Kernel related bug. Kindly upgrade linux kernel to latest version.
You can find detailed analysis of issue here - https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/analysis_of_strange_hotspot_crashes
There is an already existing issue in JDK - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161645
that recommend you to upgrade to latest kernel version